# Trying to relay a stream and getting errors most of the time

Tags: ffmpeg, nginx

I'm streaming on **Server 1** with this:

```
ffmpeg -re -i game1080_4500k-5m.mp4 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 6000k -maxrate 6000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -f flv rtmp://1.1.1.1/live
```

On **Server 2** I'm running NGINX and listening for RTMP. I'm trying to pass it on to Youtube with:

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i rtmp://1.1.1.1/live -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k -bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 160k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -async 1 -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/xxxx"
```

Sometimes it works (seems I have to wait about 30 seconds though before I run the ffmpeg command on Server 2), but most of the time it shows me errors I haven't seen before, like this:

```
[flv @ 0x55e9c1365f80] New video stream 0:1 at pos:139320 and DTS:63.534s
```

Comment: Why do ffmpeg → ffmpeg → YouTube instead of ffmpeg → YouTube?

Comment: Good question, I'm mimicking a use-case of a project I'm working on, in that we have an external feed coming in (Server 1), and then we will need to add additional things on with Server 2.